# How can I give a service principal access to create resource groups in Azure?

Tags: permissions, azure, resource-management

I am trying to create a **service principal** a.k.a. *app registrations* in **Azure** that has the required permissions to create and delete *resource groups* (and proceed to manage the resources of those resource groups after).

When I create a *service principal*, it only has access to the content of resource group that itself belongs to.

Here is a screenshot of my attempt so far. This is under App registrations:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is right, you need give your service principle `Contributor` role.

Note: **Contributor** can create and manage all types of Azure resources but can’t grant access to others.

You could do it on Azure Portal. `<your subscription>--><Access Control>--><Add>`.

[image]

More information about this please refer to this [official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).